# CSS styles are completely missing when retrieved from server, why?

Tags: css, apache

Have to say I really don't understand how come this could happen:

I've done some code in html, css and a little bit of javascript, nothing fancy, 
and just uploaded to two host servers, one to [my commercial hosting](http://mindinscription.net/webapp/coastalbooks/), the other to [uni server](http://apww04.riv.csu.edu.au:8116/coastalbooks/).

The funny thing is my commercial server renders exactly as what I can see on localhost, which is of course the expected result. However, the page rendering on uni server is a nightmare:

The CSS stylesheets, although are retrieved from server (verified using Firefox and checked http responses), do nothing to page elements as if there were not there...which I don't understand why?

There is nothing different in my code I believe, I've used two different FTP tools to transfer the code. The only different that I can tell are the server environments, particularly one is Apache 2.0+ and the uni Apache 1.3.3

But I reckon client-side code would not really depend on Apache server versions, would it?

Thanks for any suggestion in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server where it doesn't work is sending the CSS file back with the wrong MIME-type (`text/plain` instead of `text/css`). Recent browsers are liable to ignore CSS files that don't carry the correct MIME-type. So yes, it is an issue of server configuration (`mod_mime` for Apache).